# Solving the integral $\int \frac{x+1}{x (x^2+1)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm having trouble with the following integral:
$$\int \frac{x+1}{x (x^2+1)}dx$$
Through tedious partial fraction decomposition and term-by-term integration I got the following antiderivative:
$$-\frac{1}2 \log(x^2+1)+\log(|x|)+\arctan(x)+C$$
But the book gives the answer:
$$ \log(|x|) + \arctan(x) + C $$

I've already turned this in (it's not graded for correctness), but I want to know what the simplest way is to calculate this integral correctly.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha, as well as my own calculations, agree with you. Your book is probably wrong.

Comment: It you are unsure, try to differentiate both answers to find out which is correct.

Comment: The answer in the book is for $\int \frac{x^2+x+1}{x (x^2+1)}dx$

Answer (score 1):

Partial fractions gives

$$
\frac{x + 1}{x(x^2 + 1)} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x - 1}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{x^2 + 1} +  \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}
$$

Which integrates to
$$\log x - \frac{1}{2} \log(x^2 + 1) + \tan^{-1}(x) + C$$

as you found. I think the solution in your book might be incorrect.

Comment: Or else the OP made more mistakes in copying from his book then merely forgetting the $dx$.

Comment: @GEdgar Ah well, I added it, let's give him the benefit of doubt...